# Deployment ERC-6551 registry fails on OP sepolia: contract not recognised. With named imports it does deploy, but with incorrect address

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, foundry

I am trying to deploy the ERC-6551 registry (v0.2.0) on the OP sepolia testnet using forge (0.2.0), following the exact steps as described at the tokenbound.org website: https://docs.tokenbound.org/guides/deploy-registry.

Everything works fine - also the address computes correctly - until the deployment fails:

```js
  [9079256848778899809] DeployRegistry::run()
    ├─ [0] VM::envUint("MAINNET_PRIVATE_KEY") [staticcall]
    │   └─ ← <env var value>
    ├─ [0] VM::startBroadcast(<pk>)
    │   └─ ← ()
    ├─ [0] → new <unknown>@0xae0e2e915D9A2DBA5BAd9De84C39e15Ddd5b45c2
    │   └─ ← 0 bytes of code
    └─ ← EvmError: Revert
```

Notice the line `new <unknown>@0xae0e2e915D9A2DBA5BAd9De84C39e15Ddd5b45c2`: it seems the contract is not recognised.

To make things weirder: when I change the ERC6551Registry.sol contract to use named imports the deployment works.

Thus, from:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "openzeppelin-contracts/utils/Create2.sol";

import "./interfaces/IERC6551Registry.sol";
import "./lib/ERC6551BytecodeLib.sol";

contract ERC6551Registry is IERC6551Registry { 
...
```

to:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {Create2} from "../../lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/utils/Create2.sol";
import {IERC6551Registry} from "../../src/interfaces/IERC6551Registry.sol";
import {ERC6551BytecodeLib} from "../../src/lib/ERC6551BytecodeLib.sol";

contract ERC6551Registry is IERC6551Registry {
...
```

But in this case the computed address is (obviously) no longer correct.

What is going on here? Am I missing something? Is there a way to work around this issue and have the contract be recognised without named imports? Thank you!